# Eclipse/ADT giving hundreds of errors "resource entry is already defined"

Tags: android, eclipse, internationalization, resources

I am using the latest Eclipse that comes with the Android Developer Tools (ADT) on Linux (ADT v21.1.0-569685).
I inherited a large Android project, and Eclipse will not build it.

There are hundreds of errors like this: "error: Resource entry about is already defined".

In res/values/string.xml:
    `<string name="about">About</string>`

In res/values-de/string.xml:
    `<string name="about">Über</string>`

As far as I know, this is the common and correct way to do i18n on Android, but Eclipse is treating it all as errors.

This is not the "already defined" error with "main" resource and XML execution that is asked and answered elsewhere.  I'm not running any XML transform, and I have no "extra" XML files anywhere.

It doesn't seem to be an eclipse configuration error, because if I make a small sample project with the exact same entries, the duplication does not cause a "already defined" error.

Comment: Try going to Project -> Clean

Comment: Yes, I've cleaned and rebuilt many times. The same errors always occur.

Comment: Are you sure it is an Android project and not a standard eclipse project?

Comment: Just thought I'd chime in that the project also builds via ant, and we are able to build that way OK.

Comment: Raghav, it is definitely an Android project because these errors are coming from aapt (the Android tool which compiles the resources).  It is not java code which contains the problem, it is the XML files.

Comment: When I had this problem, I formatted the project instead of a doing a clean. This caused the R files to be regenerated, which solved my problem.

Comment: Robin, what do you mean by "formatted the project"?  And aren't the R files regenerated by aapt, so they are regenerated each build anyway?

Comment: Right click --> source --> format. Yes, they should be regenerated each build, but for me, they didn't (I don't know why), which gave me the same exceptions as you are having now.

Comment: UPDATE: We found a solution. This Android project had been created with the standalone version of Eclipse, but I was trying to build it with the version of Eclipse that comes bundled with ADT.  When I tried using the standalone Eclipse directly from the Eclipse website (with ADT installed as a plugin), then the problem does not occur (the build gets much farther).  Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

This error can also happen when a combination of resource qualifiers is invalid.

For example, `drawable-xhpdi-v1` doesn't really make sense because xhdpi wasn't introduced until v8.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me when several files under res/raw directory shared the same filename (without extensions). Like, for instance :

- myFile.csv
- myFile.zip

When you load a resource from this directory, Android only need the identifier (in our case : raw/myFile) :

```
int resId = res.getIdentifier("raw/myFile","raw", ctx.getPackageName()) ;
```

Hope it helps.